Reference for the word "essay" as a preliminary drawing or sketch in the visual arts
Note: I've asked the following question on Arts & Crafts SE as well. It was asked more than three weeks ago, and it hasn't yielded an answer yet.

In literature, an essay is a name given to a piece of writing in which the author presents their arguments and experiences with regards to a certain topic.

According to this Wikipedia overview of the different senses and subsenses of 'essay', in the visual arts, the term "essay" is also designated to a preliminary drawing or sketch that forms a basis for a final painting or sculpture.

Although I imagine this may very well be the case, it appears this assertion is not backed up by a reference. I have tried finding such a reference by searching with relevant terms on Google Scholar, but haven't been able to find such a reference over there either.
I therefore wonder whether there are any research papers or other sources where the essay in the visual arts is defined as such.
Question

Are there any references (academic papers or otherwise) in which the word "essay" is defined as "a preliminary drawing or or sketch forms a basis for a final painting or sculpture" in the context of the visual arts?


Went to art school and never heard the term. Almost sounds like assay, a trial, measure, attempt.

M-W, for example, carries the hypernymic 'an initial tentative effort', but without actually referencing the arts domain.

While it is true that in the present-day English essay can be used for any 'piece of writing in which the author presents their arguments and experiences with regards to a certain topic', traditionally the word carried an implication that the arguments are not as developed as they would be in a treatise, dissertation, monograph, etc. The literary form of an essay was invented to enable authors to offer for discussion the ideas that were not yet ripe to be defended in some more rigid format. Knowing this is necessary to understanding why anybody would use the word for preliminary drawings.

I see no justification in most places that that Wikipedia essay paragraph is even true.

Below are two examples of what is possibly the required subsense of essay (though 'early dallience' is another possible reading):


His essays in sculpture, such as an "Athlete Struggling with a Python," show remarkable vigour. [The National Gallery of British
Art, Victoria and Albert Museum; via
Wikipedia]


                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     


Some of the most famous of these loan pictures have already been alluded to; of Meissonier, so recently deceased, the Exposition
contains his "View near Poissy," lent by a Philadelphia owner and a
"Reconnaissance," by a Chicago one, in addition to his essays in
sculpture and Lalauze's's fine etching of "The Halt," formerly in the
great Wilson collection, shown in the department of French etching.
[Illinois Institute of Technology; Art and Architecture; reformatted
slightly



Am I correct in reading this use of essay as close to a foray?

Yes, I'd agree that that is the more probable reading. I'm only offering it as evidence that 'essay' is used for works in art falling short of perfected masterpieces.

From OED

Etymon: French essai. < Old French essai, essay: see assay n.
(Compare Modern French "essayer" -> to try and "essai" (n.) -> try )
II.7.b.
Current from 1656 to 1793
A rough copy; a first draft.
1656 The list..entred in the Parish Book, and diligently preserved as
a record, called the first Essay. J. Harrington, Common-wealth of
Oceana 211Citation details for J. Harrington, Common-wealth of Oceana
1793 I have made an essay of a letter. G. Morris in J. Sparks, Life
of Gouverneur Morris (1832) vol. I. 417

Note

The word is not in current use in this meaning.

Its use was never restricted to the visual arts.



A rough copy or first draft is about writing, not painting and sculpting.

I don't think essay works here at all. It might be some throwback to essai (test or trial) in French but there seems to be no evidence for this usage anywhere else that I've looked.
Are there any references (academic papers or otherwise) in which the word "essay" is defined as "a preliminary drawing or or sketch forms a basis for a final painting or sculpture" in the context of the visual arts?
I believe the proper term here is: a study
Here's a definition from an actual artist:

By Marion Boddy-Evans Updated on 07/03/19
In the context of painting
or fine art, a "study" is the term used for a practice piece, a quick
painting done to capture the essence of a subject or scene, or a
painting done to try out a composition, rather than a painting done as
a final piece. A study is more refined or finished than a sketch and
can include the entire composition (everything that will be in the
final painting) or just small sections.
definition of study

Example of study:

Leonardo da Vinci
Perhaps one of the most famous in the Western canon?

It's what I'd use, but it doesn't answer OP's question.

@EdwinAshworth I don't think essay in those two hits of yours refer to prelimary sketches or studies. Maybe I'm wrong. And I'd point out that you don't define essay, either.

Following up on Mr Ashworth's comment, study may be the more usual term, but the OP did not ask what is the more usual (or otherwise preferable) term for this, but whether essay is used this way in respectable sources, other than the Wikipedia article. If you believe that the answer is no, you should say so explicitly, before proceeding to offer alternatives.

@jsw29 Where's the proof of what essay actually means? The word essay is not common and EA hasn't provided a definition of it as asked for by the OP ["essay" is defined as "a preliminary drawing or or sketch]. I said I believe etc. and do not 100% know. So what? Should I retreat to the stables?

@Lambie, it would be an unfortunate loss to this site if you were to retreat anywhere. My and Mr Ashwort's point was only that the OP's question, which you repeat in the first paragraph ('Are there any references . . . ?') calls for a yes or no answer, and that you provide neither, although you seem to imply the latter. If you don't know the answer to that question, then you should have said that. Your second paragraph could have been something like 'I don't know, but I believe that the better term is . . .', and then there would have been no need for these comments.

@jsw29 I am rather tired of being called on the carpet in the way you do it. Edwin just cites two examples from some rather old texts and say nothing else. He said: "two examples of what is possibly the required subsense of essay". So, perhaps comment on his answer, which is not a Yes or No answer at all.
